# fire an event when a message is opened in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to fire an event when the user opens his messages from a particular sender. I am thinking of using a `Service` which fires that event when the user opens his messages.
First, I would like to know if this thing is feasible? I mean, is it possible to get the info that the user has opened his messages (of a particular user in Android)?

Second, is using `Service` the only way I can get through it? Is there any other method?

Thank you guys in advance :) ...

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, is it possible to get the info that the user has opened his messages (of a particular user in Android)?

You fail to say what sort of "messages" you are referring to, or what app those "messages" would be viewed in.

That being said, unless the app's developer is leaking private data (like "message" recipients) via some broadcast `Intent`, you cannot get the information you seek.

Comment: alright let me a bit more clear with the app. The app would start a service which fires an event when the user opens his messages (of a particular sender).. The messages which he receives on his NUMBER. `by the way The app doesn't deal with the sending or receiving of messages.
and here am talking about the messages which he has received on his NUMBER.

Comment: @anonymous: "when the user opens his messages (of a particular sender)" -- you could be referring to email messages, chat messages, text messages (SMS), etc. Regardless, most apps that deal with "messages" of any form will not be announcing when the user opens the app to deal with a "message", let alone who the "recipient" is, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: am sorry about that sir. yes am talking about the text messages. and am talking about the basic messaging service provided by the handset. is there any way to get that info via a service..  that user has opened his messages of a particular sender ?

Comment: @anonymous: Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.